# apacheのバーチャルホスト設定について

Tags: apache

apacheのバーチャルホストについて設定を行い
example.comでapacheの開発環境
/var/www/html/example
にアクセスすることができました。

がlocalhostにアクセスすることができません。
192.168.33.10にはアクセスできます。
/etc/httpd/conf.d/localhost.confファイルには以下を記述しています。

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
AllowOverride All
Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
</Directory>
ErrorLog logs/local-error_log
CustomLog logs/local-access_log combined env=!no_log
</VirtualHost>
```

ローカルマシンのwindowsのhostsファイルには以下を記述しています。

```
192.168.33.10 localhost
```

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが
検索しても情報が見つけられず質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

以下追記させていただきます。

今回実行している環境は
windows10上にvirtualboxにてcentos6を構築し
その中にapache2.2.15を入れている状況です。

Comment: ブラウザ等クライアントは何を使用していますか？Chrome等一部のブラウザはhostsにかかわらずに `(*.\.)?localhost` をloとして扱っていた気がします

Answer (score 2):

一般的に localhost は ループバックアドレス (127.0.0.1) を指す名前ですので Windows10上でのlocalhostはWindows10ですし、CentOS6上でのlocalhostはCentOS6です。

ご質問の環境では、Windows10上でlocalhostにアクセスした際に、CentOS6に接続させたいのだと思いますが 通常の使い方ではないので別の事を考えたほうが良いと思います。

例えば Centos6 側の ホスト名を設定して Windows10 側の hosts ファイルに書く、またはホスト名ではなく Centos6 の IP アドレスで接続するのが良いと思います。

余談ですが、名前解決にはhostsファイルとDNS参照などがありますが、どのように名前解決するかはアプリケーションごとに異なります。特にブラウザは独自にキャッシュしていることもあるので 個人的な好みで言いますと、特に支障がなければIPアドレスでアクセスするのが悩みが少なくていいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。その後いろいろ設定をテストしていたのですが動きが不安定でした。しかし、ご説明をいただいて少し納得がいきました。冷静に考えればわかりそうでしたが、ごっちゃになっておりました。centos6のIPアドレスを基準にテスト環境を考えたいと思います。またブラウザごとの挙動の違いもご教授いただきありがとうございます。こちらもわかってすっきりしました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

末尾の"/"を外しましょう。
その後、Apacheを再起動して変わりませんか？

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

---

少し考えたのですが、このApacheを実行しているサーバと
実際見ているWindowsって別物ですか？
`localhost`って自分を指すものなので別のサーバを見せたいなら別の仮想ドメインにしたほうがいいです。
`hosts`とどちらが強いか分かりませんが、
基本的に`localhost`は`127.0.0.1`や`::1`といった自分を見るものなので
動作しないのであれば`localhost`以外でも試してみるといいです。

---

`localhost`を`hosts`で別IPに参照させてみたところ
`ping`で別IPに送信されているので`hosts`で上書きは出来るようです。
こちらでVirtualBoxで立てたサーバに接続できるか試験してみました。
ブラウザによっては`localhost`で自分を呼ぶようですね。

- IE：OK
- FireFox：OK
- Chrome：NG
- Opera：NG

また、Apacheの設定もテストしましたが動作しているようです。
ただし、誤字を１つ見つけました。`Options -FollowSymLinks -Indexes`に"-"がありません。

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
        Options -FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog logs/local-error_log
    CustomLog logs/local-access_log combined env=!no_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。パスを指定してみましたがやはりうまくいきませんでした。環境の件追記させていただきます。またapacheのログで気になったところですがclient 192.168.33.1という記述があり現在調査しています。もしほかに見るべきところがありましたら是非突っ込みをお願いいたします。他のドメイン（.com）などのバーチャルホストに関しては問題なく動いています。作業的にはその都度ディレクトリをしていして行えば行けるのですが、localhostも使えたほうがいいのと、原因を知りたいというので質問させていただきました。

Comment: 追記しました。……出来たとは言え、`localhost`は、あまり使うべき名称ではないと思います。

Comment: 度々のコメントありがとうございます！誤字を修正して再度テストしましたがfirefoxでもだめでした。localhost.comにすると難なく表示するのですが^^；色々ご回答いただきまして恐縮です。おそらく当方が勉強中で初心者のため何らかの設定でlocalhostがおかしくなっている状況だと思います。localhostはあまり使わないほうがいいのですね。書籍などではよく出てくるので何とか仕えたほうがいいのかと思っておりました。実際の現場などで使っていないようであればlocalhost.comとして学習環境を動かしていきたいと思います。

Comment: 当方、Win7のためもしかしたらWin10では`localhost`が強くて`ping`も飛ばないかもしれないですね。

Comment: OSの仕様なども関連ありそうですね。また具体的に解決策が見つかりましたらこちらに共有したいと思います。ありがとうございました！